# Fazer um histograma com uma curva gaussiana em Python

Tags: python, gráfico, histograma

É a primeira vez que faço um histograma em Python, mas não estou a conseguir fazer o mesmo histograma em Python, que obtive no Excel. Além disso, queria colocar uma curva gaussiana e a média com a incerteza da mesma ao lado do gráfico como vi num artigo.
O histograma que realizei no Excel é o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu estou a tentar criar um histograma em que no eixo xx apareça o tamanho dos lados dos triângulos que estou a medir, em micrómetros e no eixo yy apareça a frequência relativa com que aparecem estes triângulos.
Os dados que utilizei para obter o gráfico Excel são os seguintes:

```
Tamanho  Frequência relativa
  0-1          0,282
  1-2          0,316
  2-3          0,171
  3-4          0,068
  4-5          0,085
  5-6          0,026
  6-7          0,026
  7-8          0,009
  8-9          0,009
  9-10         0,000
  10-11        0,000
  11-12        0,009
```

Eu gostava de realizar um histograma em Python parecido com o deste artigo ("Okada et al., Gas-Source CVD Growth of Atomic Layered WS2 from WF6 and H2S precursors with High Grain Size Uniformity, 2019"):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

em que aparece o histograma, a curva gaussiana e a média da curva com a incerteza.
Tentei fazer em Python, mas não consegui que me aparecesse a frequência relativa no eixo dos yy do histograma. Vou colocar aqui a minha tentativa de resolução sem sucesso no Python feito num Jupyter Notebook do Anaconda:

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
datafile=Path('/Users/maria/Desktop/graficosTese', 'amostra22Atriangulos.xlsx')
df=pd.read_excel(datafile, 
                 index_col=0)
df.head()
df.hist(column='Frequência relativa')
```

O meu ficheiro Excel tem a seguinte estrutura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém me poderia ajudar a fazer o histograma com a curva gaussiana onde estivesse a equação da média com a incerteza no gráfico? Muito obrigada

Erro obtido agora:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como você tem os dados de frequência prontos, creio que não precisa fazer recurso às funções que criam histogramas, como `plt.hist` do matplotlib e `sns.distplot` do seaborn. De todo modo, vale uma lida na documentação já que essa é a forma mais comum de construir histogramas ([matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/gallery/statistics/hist.html), [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html)).

No caso do seu problema, porém, basta um gráfico de barras:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from unidecode import unidecode
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame({'frequencia_relativa': {'0-1': 0.282, '1-2': 0.316, '2-3': 0.171, '3-4': 0.068, '4-5': 0.085, '5-6': 0.026, '6-7': 0.026, '7-8': 0.009, '8-9': 0.009, '9-10': 0.0, '10-11': 0.0, '11-12': 0.009}})

df=df.reindex(['0-1', '1-2', '2-3', '3-4', '4-5', '5-6', '6-7',
       '7-8', '8-9', '9-10', '10-11', '11-12'])


fig, ax=plt.subplots()
ax.bar(x=df.index, height=df.frequencia_relativa)
ax.set_yticklabels(["{:.2f}".format(k).replace(".",",") for k in np.arange(0.,0.35,0.05)])
plt.show()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A segunda parte do problema (i.e., plotar uma distribuição gaussiana) também é possível fazer de forma manual, embora minha indicação é que você use uma kernel. Segue exemplo (usando como parâmetros a média e o desvio-padrão da planilha):

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

df=pd.DataFrame({'frequencia_relativa': {'0-1': 0.282, '1-2': 0.316, '2-3': 0.171, '3-4': 0.068, '4-5': 0.085, '5-6': 0.026, '6-7': 0.026, '7-8': 0.009, '8-9': 0.009, '9-10': 0.0, '10-11': 0.0, '11-12': 0.009}})
df=df.reindex(['0-1', '1-2', '2-3', '3-4', '4-5', '5-6', '6-7',
       '7-8', '8-9', '9-10', '10-11', '11-12'])

fig, ax=plt.subplots()
ax.bar(x=df.index, height=df.frequencia_relativa, alpha=0.5)
ax.set_yticklabels(["{:.2f}".format(k).replace(".",",") for k in np.arange(0.,0.35,0.05)])

x_axis = np.arange(0, 10, 0.001)
#normal com média 2,232 e variância 1.88, conforme planilha
plt.plot(x_axis, norm.pdf(x_axis,2.232,1.88))
plt.show()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Boa tarde. Obrigada pela sua resposta. Se calhar expliquei-me mal. Eu pretendo criar exatamente o mesmo gráfico com as barras azuis que coloquei no post. Esse gráfico foi criado no Excel mas queria no Python porque fica mais profissional na Tese de Mestrado. Para tal, os valores das alturas das barras devem ser as frequências relativas (0,282; 0,316; 0,171, etc). Não percebi o que quis dizer com “dados absolutos”. Gostava que o gráfico tivesse a distribuição gaussiana com apenas uma bossa em vez de duas. Acha que conseguiria editar a sua resposta por favor? Obrigada pelo esforço

Comment: O gráfico que pretendo tem 12 barras que vão de 1 a 12 em intervalos de uma unidade. As alturas do gráfico seriam as frequências relativas que coloquei acima (0,282; 0,316; 0,171; 0,068; etc). O gráfico tem de ser exatamente igual ao gráfico que fiz no Excel com barras azuis, mas na altura não consegui colocar a curva gaussiana no Excel e precisava-a de a ajustar aos dados.

Comment: Ok. Vou editar agora.

Comment: Muito obrigada pela edição, Lucas! Era mesmo esse gráfico que pretendia! Eu tentei colocar o seu código no Jupyter Notebook do Anaconda mas está a aparecer-me o erro que coloquei no fim do post. Sabe como poderia resolver? Já agora, quando faz o desvio padrão na distribuição normal do seu código e coloca 1.88, isso que temos de colocar aí é o desvio padrão da amostra ou é o desvio padrão da média (desvio padrão/raíz quadrada de N, sendo N o número de amostras)? Muito obrigada e desculpe estar a incomodar

Comment: poderia partilhar como colocou o seu ficheiro csv ou fazer o código para o ficheiro excel do post sff?

Comment: adicionei o csv no post scriptum

Comment: Peço imensa desculpa, mas infelizmente não estou a conseguir executar o código mesmo transformando o Excel para csv. Não percebo porque não funciona. Não conseguiria se faz favor alterar o código para que lesse o ficheiro Excel do post, por favor? Seria de uma grande, grande ajuda

Comment: Para seu código funcionar com o ficheiro do excel, basta apagar a linha `df.frequencia_relativa=[float(k.replace(",",".")) for k in df.frequencia_relativa]`. Pq no seu programa a coluna `frequencia_relativa` já está sendo lida como float. Não há necessidade de transformar a variável. Eu precisei transformar pq não tenho excel e o python lê números separados por vírgulas como string em arquivos csv

Comment: Eu tentei mas continua a dar-me erro. Coloquei o erro na última imagem do post. O que estarei a fazer de errado?

Comment: Eu já sei o que fazer. Vou editar a resposta para incluir a definição do dado dentro do programa. Para não precisar importar arquivos. Um minuto

Comment: Veja se resolveu, @CarmenGonzález

Comment: Você é um génio! Me salvou! Muito obrigada! Já agora, quando faz o desvio padrão na distribuição normal do seu código e coloca 1.88, isso que temos de colocar aí é o desvio padrão da amostra ou é o desvio padrão da média (desvio padrão/raíz quadrada de N, sendo N o número de amostras)?

Comment: Agora você me pegou. Não sei. Essa é uma pergunta de estatística, creio que o fórum mais apropriado seria o Cross-Validated. Segue link: https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Se eu nos números do eixo dos yy em vez de ponto, quisesse colocar vírgula, no gráfico que fizeste, que linha de código poderia usar? Penso que o Python por definição coloca ponto por representar dessa forma os decimais.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117594/discussion-between-lucas-and-carmen-gonzalez).